# Check if server is up

Tags: tcl, expect, ping

I want to write a script to check if a server is up, and if not, sleep for 30 seconds and ping again. But I only want it to repeat the cycle for 10 minutes or 20 times. I need to use this because, my other script updates a machine and system reboots, so I need to wait for it to come back again. I don't want to set up a huge sleep time, because that's just inefficient.

I am pinging 0.0.0.0 just as an example.

Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 30
set max_try 20
set tries 0
spawn ping 0.0.0.0

expect {
    "64 bytes from 0.0.0.0" puts "servers are up"
    if [ $tries -eq $max_try ]; then
            puts "Test machine taking too long to reboot"
            exit
    fi
    timeout {incr tries;exp_continue}
 }
 puts "Going to exit now"
 exit
```

Comment: **Standard caveat:** Ping only tests if the network interface is up, not if any real service on the system is up. I have seen systems that responded to ping despite being completely unusable (due to all user processes being broken). Any monitoring solution, whether temporary as in what you're doing or persistent as in something like nagios, _needs_ to bear these sorts of things in mind or the results it will deliver will be completely bogus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you don't need expect for this at all. In bash

```
function ping1 {
    command ping -c 1 -W 1 "$1" >/dev/null
}

function ping2 {
    if ! ping1 "$1"; then
        sleep 120
        ping1 "$1"
    fi
}

host="0.0.0.0"
if ping2 "$host"; then
    echo "$host is up"
else
    echo "$host is down"
fi
```

new requirements

```
function ping_many {
    local tries=$1 host=$2 sleep=$3
    while (( tries-- > 0 )) && ! ping1 "$host"; do
        sleep "$sleep"
    done
    return $(( ! (tries >= 0) ))  # have to invert the boolean value to a success/fail value
}

ping_many 20 0.0.0.0 30
```

Comment: Thank you, this would work, but I just realized that having a 2 minute checkup is too much time. I have changed to the checkups to 30 seconds and have it loop 20 times. I know that I can't make 20 new fuctions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in case anyone else interested. \003 means ctrl+c

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 5
set max_try 20
for {set i 0} {$i < $max_try} {incr i 1} {
        puts "loop $i"
        spawn ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 0.0.0.0
        expect {
                "2 packets transmitted, 2 received" {puts "servers are up"; break}
                timeout {send \003}
        }
        sleep 30
}
puts "about to exit now";
exit
```